# Hyphenation in listings captions doesn't work correctly

Tags: listings, captions, hyphenation

I have the problem that automatic hyphenation in listings caption doesn't work if automatic linebreaking is activated. It works if I set `breaklines=false` or `captionpos=t`, which is weird. Is there a workaround? I want to have captions at the bottom and I need automatic line-breaking.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{
   breaklines=true,
   captionpos=b
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={information information information information information information information}]
A = B
C = D
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

`captionpos=b` (WRONG):

[image]

`captionpos=t` (correct):

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is the line

```
\hbadness\@M \pretolerance\@M
```

of `lstmisc` and the macro `\lst@AddToHook{Init}` which is set *before* the listings contents with `breaklines=true`. With `captionpos=t` it doesn't belong to the caption, but with `captionpos=b` it does. It prevents hyphenation. A simple fix is to reset `\pretolerance`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
   breaklines=true,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption=information  information  information information information information information,captionpos=t]
A = B
C = D
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={\pretolerance=100 information information information information 
information information information},captionpos=b]
A = B
C = D
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

A better solution is to reset the values inside `\lst@MakeCaption` which should be reported to the current maintainer of `listings`.